# How can I repair Webpack issue on React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Trying to install this React script:
https://github.com/webdesignleader/referBeam

Followed the readme but think there might be version issues or something.

Error Log:

```
$ webpack
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'resolve-cwd'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/nodejs/webpack/node_modules/import-local/index.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/webpack/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/webpack/node_modules/import-local/index.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/nodejs/webpack/node_modules/import-local/index.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/webpack/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
  ]
}


$ sudo webpack
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { defaultRules?, exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp? }
   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
```